Is there any way in which orbits emitting gravitational waves could avoid coalescence?
In the very far future, all orbits will eventually coalesce as they lose orbital energy through gravitational waves emission.
However, can there be 3-body or N-body interactions in which the members of the system do not coalesce (but not by having any of them ejected)?

You have already posted this on Astronomy SE. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/58379/will-all-orbits-emitting-gravitational-waves-inevitably-coalesce

@ProfRob one of the commenters said that it was probably better to ask this question on this site instead of Astronomy SE. Should I delete the one in Astronomy SE?

The answer is no as long as the system is emitting gravitational waves. If GWs are emitted, the system is continually losing energy (and angular momentum) inevitably driving the system closer together leading to coalescence.
The only way to avoid this is if the system is in (or is asymptoting to) a configuration that does not emit gravitational waves. This essentially requires all mass (and mass-current) multipoles of the system to be stationary. One configuration would be a ring of (infinite) particles  orbiting their common center of gravity. This configuration would be a solution to the equations of motion that is perfectly stationary and would not emit any gravitational waves. (It would not be very stable though.)
With a finite number of particles you might be able to asymptote to this configuration by repeatedly splitting the particles. You might be able to do this fast enough to avoid coalescence in finite time. (Of course, you are going to hit a quantum limit for the splitting the particles at some point.)

even some special orbital configurations of many satellites or planets that, by resonance, they exchange orbital energy among the members of the orbits so that the lost energy from gravitational waves could be compensated? @TimRias

If the configuration is leaking energy to infinity in the form of gravitational waves, then no.

I was suggested in the question I asked in Astronomy SE that if one star in a binary system were disrupted into a gaseous ring, then it would be invariant and the pair would not emit gravity waves. Is this true? Or would the ring also have to consist of infinitely many gas particles? @TimRias

@vengaq Strictly ( and purely classically) speaking. Yes it would still require infinite particles. In practice however the number of particles in such a ring would be effectively infinite. Moreover the inhomogeneities in the cloud would be so small that one would have to worry about the quantum behavior of the gravitational waves. We do not know if we can trust the known laws of physics in that regime.
